# Convert Euler to Heun (improved Euler)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I already have implemented Euler method in Mathematica.
Now I want to convert this method to Heun method (improved Euler).

I have this Euler implementation:

```
a = 2;(*my a parameter*)
b = .01;                 (*my b parameter*)
x = 0;                   (*starting x value*)
p = 1;                   (*starting p value*)
t = 1;                   (*step size t*)
f[p_] := a p - b p^2;    (*my function*)
f[0] = 1;
eulertable = {};         (*build table (x,p).n steps in loop*)
For[n = 1, 
 n <= 21, n++, 
  AppendTo[eulertable, {x, p}];
  p = p + t f[p];
  x = x + t;]
```

Now I want to implement this with the Heun method. I already have this implementation of the Heun method.

```
heun[f_, {x_, x0_, xn_}, {y_, y0_}, steps_] :=
 Block[{ xold = x0, yold = y0, sollist = {{x0, y0}}, x, y, h },
 h = N[(xn - x0) / steps]; 
 Do[ xnew = xold + h;
     k1 = h * (f /. {x -> xold, y -> yold});
     k2 = h * (f /. {x -> xold + h, y -> yold + k1});
     ynew = yold + .5 * (k1 + k2);
     sollist = Append[sollist, {xnew, ynew}];
     xold = xnew;
     yold = ynew,
 {steps}
 ];
 Return[sollist]
 ]
```

But I need to convert this method to have the input like it is in my Euler method. So I have to convert the Heun method that I have the parameter a, b, x, t, p, f[].

As I am new with Mathematica I am having problems to convert the method.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put `f[0]=1`?

Replace

```
p = p + t f[p];
x = x + t;
```

with

```
p1 = p + t f[p];
p2 = p + t f[p1];
p = (p1+p2)/2;
x = x + t;
```

Your step size is rather large for the values of your parameters.